# Django Rest Framework - create object with field value from URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use a ModelViewSet to create an instance from a POST request where one of the field values is specified in the URL?

EG: POST /teams/3/members with data `name = Bob` should create `Member(team_id=3, name="Bob")`

Conceptually similar to [filtering against the url](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it and quite simple, look here, that would be your url:

```
re_path('teams/(?P<team_id>\d+)/members/', views.MemberViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create_member'}), name='members'),
```

and in views just use `team_id` as an argument:

```
#class MemberViewSet
    def create_member(request, team_id):
       ...
```